# How do I find the incremental upgrades direct download links?

Tags: ota-update

Some time ago, I found this page that contains links for incremental upgrades: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=20843237&postcount=1

I'd like to know if there is a way to find such links for myself. If I try to go to http://android.clients.google.com/ I get a 404 error.

Comment: OTA for yakju is out: http://android.clients.google.com/packages/ota/google_maguro/24a9a760f32e.signed-yakju-JZO54K-from-JRO03C.24a9a760.zip

Comment: Please see [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device) for your second question, we like to keep all of that in one place and give general advice rather than specific links for every device and version, which would get out of hand.  It may also answer your primary question somewhat ... I don't think there's a simple way to see all possible updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it goes something like this:

- somebody gets the OTA update on their phone
- they use a logcat tool to find the URL in the logs.
- they post the URL on some forum.

Source: http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-droid-incredible/31295-how-get-ota-download-location-share.html#post309933